# Device Single Sign-On

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, single-sign-on

I'm trying to implement Device Single Sign-On for a couple applications I'm "experimenting" with. The apps are in the same WL 6.2 project and are based on the "Form Based Authentication" Tutorial on developers site.

Ignoring the obvious - that I mistyped something - I'm mostly baffled that it works in the iOS Simulator, but not on my iPhone. I realize that working on the iOS simulator is no guarantee for the real device.

Someone showed me a video on this topic using an Android device, so I suppose the large question is - should this work on an iPhone? If so, any thoughts on what to look for?

TIA

-bob-

Comment: It would be more beneficial, Bob, if you'll provide something that we can help you with. Like a demo project so that this could be debugged, or some actual implementation notes and code snippets of your application as well as error logs.

Comment: Thanks for responding and apologies for lack of details. I was reluctant to send my two projects due to size. As it turns out, i was "signing" the apps improperly in XCODE.

Once I confirmed that the ID prefix was the same, it started to work. Item 3 at this link

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_enabling_simple_data_sharing_native_iOS.html

Comment: Thanks. Please write it as an answer so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, by user3530200:

> i was "signing" the apps improperly in XCODE. Once I confirmed that
>   the ID prefix was the same, it started to work. Item 3 at this link. For reference, step 3 @ http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_enabling_simple_data_sharing_native_iOS.html